# CSS only select an element by a sibling's selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this html (snipped for brevity)

```
<label>
    <div class="label">Condition</div>
    <select>
        <option value="blah" selected="selected">Blah</option> 
        <option value="other...">other...</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="condition" value="" style="display: none;">
</label>
```

I want to get the **select** element.  The only static/non-generic factor I can see is the input[name='condition'] but the generic sibling selector won't help be because the 'select' comes before the input.  So something like `input[name='condition'] ~ select`does not work.

This element moves, sometimes is the first, sometimes the twentieth and can be any and all locations in between so nth isn't going to work.

I know how to get this with Javascript/Jquery but that is not an option here.  I only have CSS selectors available.  So the big question is, is there any way to get the 'select' out of this HTML using only CSS selectors?

Is there any way to get a select element that has an option element with a value='something'?

Comment: I am not at all clear on what you want to do. You can get the select with `select { /*styles*/ }` — if you need to distinguish this select from others on the page you can try `div.label + select { /*styles*/ }`, but you can't select an element based on one of its _child_ elements.

Comment: You can't access the `<select>`, or any other, element based on a later sibling. This is impossible if the only consistent element is the identified element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code:

```
div.label ~ select
```

It returns any selects that are preceded by a div with class label.

Comment: Presumably, `div.label` is a "generic" element that exists for *all* of the `<label>` entries. The OP wants to select the list based on a "static/non-generic" element (something unique to a particular `<label>` entry), like "an option element with a value='something'". `The only static/non-generic factor I can see is the input[name='condition'] but the generic sibling selector won't help be because the 'select' comes before the input.` -- OP

Comment: showdev is correct - thanks for looking at this Steve but I've considered your idea already and there can be several selects on my page that would match this selector.

Answer (score 0):

If the common parent element is always a `label`, you can use `label:has(input[name="condition"]) select` as a selector:

```css
label:has(input[name="condition"]) select {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <div class="label">Condition</div>
    <select>
        <option value="blah" selected="selected">Blah</option> 
        <option value="other...">other...</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="condition" value="" style="display: none;">
</label>
```

If there are also other parent elements apart from `label`, you might also use the "all selector" `*` as a parent, like `*:has(input[name="condition"]) > select`. In this case I'd use the `>` in between to make sure only direct children are addressed:

```css
*:has(input[name="condition"]) > select {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="label">Condition</div>
    <select>
        <option value="blah" selected="selected">Blah</option> 
        <option value="other...">other...</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="condition" value="" style="display: none;">
</div>
```